# Can pl/pgsql function take a variable number of parameters?

Tags: stored-procedures, plpgsql, parameter, variadic

I have a database with multiple schemas which have the same tables and views, and I want to create a procedure that creates a view from one the views in the schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_summary_view(
    created_view character varying,
    common_view character varying,
    schema_1 character varying,        
    schema_2 character varying,        
    schema_3 character varying,
    ...
    schema_x character varying,        
)
```

`create_view` is the view that will be created, `common_view` is the view that is identical in all the schemas, and `schema_x` are the list of schemas whose `common_view`s are being joined into `created_view`.

Does pl/pgsql have a syntax for indicating a variable number of parameters? `created_view`, `common_view` and at least `one schema_x` is required?

An alternative I'm considering it to pass a comma or space separated string of the schemas and use `regexp_split_to_array` to break it up, but it would be good to know of variable length arguments are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variadic function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_summary_view(
   created_view text,
   common_view text,
   VARIADIC schemas text[]
) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql AS
$$SELECT format('CREATE VIEW %I AS ', created_view) ||
         string_agg(
            format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I', schemas[i], common_view),
            ' UNION ALL '
         )
FROM generate_series(1, cardinality(schemas)) AS i$$;
```

Here is an invocation:

```
SELECT create_summary_view('newv', 'oldv', 's1', 's2', 's3');

                                            create_summary_view                                            
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 CREATE VIEW newv AS SELECT * FROM s1.oldv UNION ALL SELECT * FROM s2.oldv UNION ALL SELECT * FROM s3.oldv
(1 row)
```

Comment: Laurenz thanks for the additional example of the view