# What function do I need to get single quoted constants in the generated SQL? The code generator wraps the single-quoted output in double quotes

Tags: postgresql, syntax, quoted-identifier, code-generation

I wanted to create a view that sums a table common to a number of schemas, as expressed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333273/can-pl-pgsql-function-take-a-variable-number-of-parameters/333311#333311), and includes the schema name or a derived expression as a column, so I created a view that includes the schema name as a constant value, by using the `quote_literal` to wrap the schema name in single quotes.

The `quote_literal` may not be the right function here, but whatever I do gets wrapped in the double quotes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_summary_view_quoted(
   created_view text,
   common_view text,
   VARIADIC schemas text[]
) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql AS
$$SELECT format('CREATE VIEW %I AS ', created_view) ||
         string_agg(
            format('SELECT %I as source_schema, * FROM %I.%I ', quote_literal(schemas[i]) , schemas[i], common_view),
            ' UNION ALL '
         )
FROM generate_series(1, cardinality(schemas)) AS i$$;
")
```

Applying it to the query

```
SELECT create_summary_view_quoted('newv', 'oldv', 's1', 's2', 's3');
```

produces

```
create view newv as
select
    "'s1'" as source_schema,
    *
from
    s1.oldv
union all
select
    "'s2'" as source_schema,
    *
from
    s2.oldv
union all
select
    "'s3'" as source_schema,
    *
from
    s3.oldv
```

The problem is the double-quote around the single-quoted constant which causes Postgres to treat is as a column name and it barfs.

I fixed the code generation issue by using double single quotes around the first placeholder and dropping the `quote_literal` function,

i.e. replace

```
format('SELECT %I as source_schema, * FROM %I.%I ', quote_literal(schemas[i]) , schemas[i], common_view),
```

with

```
format('SELECT ''%I'' as source_schema, * FROM %I.%I ', schemas[i] , schemas[i], common_view),
```

My issue is not so much with `quote_literal` but how the function always wraps the output of any function which wraps a single-quoted string with double-quotes.

Even when I used a function to strip off a leading suffix in the schema names because they are redundant the single quoted output gets wrapped in double quotes.

eg `quote_nullable(right(schemas[i],-10))` the resulting string gets double-quoted.

I could apply the `||` operator somewhere there but I prefer a quoting function.

Doesn't Postgres have a built-in single quoting function?

Is there some required SQL syntax I'm missing?

Is it a Postgres quirk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%I` [format type specifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) tells the `format()` function to treat the corresponding argument value as an identifier, and since it contains single quotes (as a result of `quote_literal()`), it is properly enclosed in double quotes to make it a valid identifier.

However, in the `SELECT` list you want the schema name as a simple string literal, so the `%s` type specifier will be appropriate.

```
format(
  'SELECT %s as source_schema, * FROM %I.%I ', 
  quote_literal(schemas[i]) ,
  schemas[i],
  common_view
)...
```

Perhaps you can also dispense with `quote_literal()`, if you know the schema names' provenance and can be sure they don't contain any single quotes:

```
format(
  'SELECT ''%s'' as source_schema, * FROM %I.%I ', 
  schemas[i],
  schemas[i],
  common_view
)...
```