# Chain 2 queries with \gexec in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'd like to produce a data dictionary from the catalog tables of a Postgres DB. I wanted to have the name of the table on one line and then the list of columns.
I've tried to do it with `\gexec`:

```
\set schema '''my_schema'''
\set fname 'out_file.txt'
\o :fname
SELECT format('
select ''>>> %I'';
select column_name, data_type, coalesce(character_maximum_length, numeric_precision), description
  from information_schema.columns
       left join pg_catalog.pg_description on objoid = ''%I.%I''::regclass and objsubid = ordinal_position
 where table_name = ''%I''', table_name, table_schema, table_name, table_name)
FROM 
   information_schema.tables
where table_schema = :schema
order by table_name
\gexec
\o
```

But the first statement seems to be omitted and the name of the table doesn't appear in the result.
Of course, I could simply add the table name in every row but for my purpose, this means an extra process after to put all this in a proper documentation.

Is there a way to have the result of the 2 queries in the result file?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `%s` when printing the table name. [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333724/what-function-do-i-need-to-get-single-quoted-constants-in-the-generated-sql-the/) seems related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`\gexec`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-GEXEC) ...

> Sends the current query buffer to the server, then treats **each
> column of each row** of the query's output (if any) as an SQL
> statement to be executed.

Bold emphasis mine.
Currently, you generate one column with multiple statements. Put **each statement in a separate column** to achieve your objective:

```
\set schema 'my_schema'
\set fname 'out_file.txt'
\o :fname
SELECT format('select ''>>> %I'';', table_name)
     , format('select column_name, data_type, coalesce(character_maximum_length, numeric_precision), description
               from information_schema.columns
               left join pg_catalog.pg_description on objoid = ''%I.%I''::regclass and objsubid = ordinal_position
               where table_name = %L', table_schema, table_name, table_name)
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema = :'schema'
ORDER  BY table_name\gexec
\o
```

Note some minor fixes to quoting names.

###### Aside

`coalesce(character_maximum_length, numeric_precision)` seems odd: it's lumping two quite distinct numbers together.
Also, I would rather query the system catalog `pg_attribute` to get better information for types and storage - among other things. Related:

- [Get column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/get-column-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view/75124#75124)
- [Query the schema details of a table in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900676/939860)
- [How to list the columns of a view in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58020843/939860)

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly except :'schema'. I have to write :schema. About coalesce(character_maximum_length, numeric_precision) : you're right, it's odd. But when column is a character string, length is in the first but when an integer, it seems to be in the second. In fact, that's not very important at this stage (for me... It's a kind of POC) but i'll have a look at pg_attribute (but i find pg_catalog much more complicated than information_schema :-) )

Comment: @Jice: The safe way is to pass the schema name unquoted and use `:'schema'` for interpolation. This handles possible single quotes in the name reliably. Else it's a possible entry vector for SQL injection.

Comment: Ah yes, i see. You're right. I'll do it